# Expressing integral as gamma function

Tags: calculus, integration, gamma-function

I was trying to compute the expected value $E[X^k]$ for a Weibull distribution, and I encountered this integral $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty t^{b+k-1}e^{-ct^b}dt$$ where $k>0$ is an integer and $c>0$. Can I somehow express it in terms of the [gamma function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function) $$\Gamma(a)=\int_0^\infty y^{a-1}e^{-y}dy$$for some $a>0$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the parameters where it's defined, the integral $\int_0^\infty$ is known as moments of the higher exponential function, which indeed is essentially a function of the Gamma function.

See

[Wikipedia: Stretched_exponential_function#Mathematical_properties](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stretched_exponential_function#Mathematical_properties)

You can start at the result and read off the parameter substitution.

Comment: I can't see how to derive the result shown in there. Any help with that?

Comment: @PJMiller: Did you try? Make a substitution so that the argument of the exponential function is linear, as in the Gamma function.

Comment: If I take $a=(t/T_k)^b$, then $da/dt = bt^{b-1}/T_k^b$. I don't see how that helps with the integration. Is that what you mean?

Comment: $y:=c\ t^b\implies t=c^{-\tfrac{1}{b}}y^\tfrac{1}{b}\implies \mathrm dt=b^{-1}c^{-\tfrac{1}{b}}y^{\tfrac{1}{b}-1}\mathrm dy\implies\int_0^\infty t^{b+k-1}e^{-c\ t^b}\mathrm dt=a_1\int_0^\infty y^{a_2}e^{-y}\mathrm dy$